# mgcv GAM with betar

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Does anyone know how to obtain the fitted phi parameter from the model output (mgcv GAM with a beta distribution)?

Referring to the [betar gam example](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-31/topics/betar) provided:

```
library(mgcv)
## Simulate some beta data...
set.seed(3);n<-400
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
mu <- binomial()$linkinv(dat$f/4-2)
phi <- .5
a <- mu*phi;b <- phi - a;
dat$y <- rbeta(n,a,b) 

bm <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=betar(link="logit"),data=dat)
```

The output shows a phi estimate under "Family:Beta regression"

```
> bm

Family: Beta regression(0.491) 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
1.73 1.63 5.62 1.00  total = 10.98
```

Comment: Hi Luis, I can see this is your first time posting. Make sure to provide reproducible examples, instead of just referring to a webpage. I edited it for you this time as I am slightly familiar with this. Next time, please take note and write a more informed question :)

Comment: Can you add some of your code of how you are trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

During the fitting, the gam function calls betar() which then estimates the phi parameter called theta. I quoted the description of the function below:

> Description:
>
> ```
>  Family for use with ‘gam’ or ‘bam’, implementing regression for
>  beta distributed data on (0,1). A linear predictor controls the
>  mean, mu of the beta distribution, while the variance is then
>  mu(1-mu)/(1+phi), with parameter phi being estimated during
>  fitting, alongside the smoothing parameters.
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  betar(theta = NULL, link = "logit",eps=.Machine$double.eps*100)
>   Arguments:
>
>  theta: the extra parameter (phi above).
> ```

Using the example you have, you just need to look under the gam object:

```
bm <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=betar(link="logit"),data=dat)
exp(bm$family$getTheta())
[1] 0.4913482
```

Comment: I suppose this is true in general and that extra fitted parameters are listed in this 'Theta'. How does one know how the parameters are transformed (exp in the case above)? I could not find this in the mgcv documentation.

Comment: Hey @LuisMier-y-Teran, I looked under the source code for the family, betar, https://github.com/cran/mgcv/blob/master/R/efam.r, and you can see that most of the time, before they feed it into the beta-binomial distribution, the exponential is taken.

Comment: +1 if you look at the `getTheta` function, you can do `getTheta(trans = TRUE)` to achieve the same thing as explicitly `exp()`-ing the result of the call to `getTheta()`.

Comment: Yes @ReinstateMonica-G.Simpson, you are right. Thanks for pointing it out.